# Can't login to website using python [requests, roboBrowser]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, robobrowser

I've been looking around for a week now. All the answers I found are either out of date or not working.

I'm trying to login to this website http://ink361.com/app/login
I tried using requests alone and I tried mixing requests with robobrowser to inject some headers.
I don't have a problem providing my username and password for testing purposes.

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
import requests
headers = {
    "Accept" : "application/json",
    "Connection" : "keep-alive",
    "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language" : "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Content-Length" : "50",
    "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    "Cookie" : '',
    "DNT" : '1',
    "Host" : "ink361.com",
    "Referer" : "http://ink361.com/app/login",
    "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0",
    "X-Request" : "JSON",
    "X-Requested-With" : "XMLHttpRequest"
}
s = requests.Session()
s.headers = headers
browser = RoboBrowser(session=s,history=True)
login_url = 'http://ink361.com/app/login'
browser.open(login_url)
forms = browser.get_forms()
print(forms)
```

I was trying to print all the forms in the web page but it takes forever then it raises

```
RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

The headers for some reason do this thing. I tried without the headers I get an empty array for the forms.
I tried grabbing the form like this

```
form = browser.get_form(class_='modern-form')
print(form.fields)
```

and I get fields are empty..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was posting to the wrong URL

http://ink361.com/app/login

instead of

http://ink361.com/v1/auth/login

People at IRC #python helped out :)